# Como criar operadores em C#?

Tags: c#, operadores

Como criar um operador em C#? Por exemplo,

Existem operadores como:

```
* multiplicacao
/ divisao
% percentual
```

A dúvida é:

Como eu posso criar meu próprio operador? Por exemplo:

```
100 ~ 2 = 200.8
```

Onde `~` seria meu operador que faria algo do tipo:

```
A ~ B = ((A * 2) + (B * 2)) / (5) 
100 ~ 2 = ((100 * 2) + (2 * 2)) / 5 = 200.8
```

Comment: Criar um operador realmente não é possível.

Comment: Eu dei uma resposta porque a atual aceita não fala as coisas mais importantes sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Criar um operador não é possível na linguagem. Então o operador `~`  só existirá se os *designers* da linguagem um dia quiserem e duvido que isto ocorra.

Alguns operadores existentes, e não todos, podem ter seu comportamento alterado em um determinado tipo - não sobrescrito. O termo usado é [sobrecarga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading).

De qualquer forma o exemplo usado não é possível. As duas expressões não fazem sentido. Porque na linguagem o `=` é o operador de atribuição ([ele não pode ser sobrecarregado](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading#overloadable-operators?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)), no lado esquerdo dele (*lvalue*) não é possível usar outros operadores como foi usado.

Ainda que isto tenha sido um erro de digitação e na verdade o operador ali fosse o `==` (que pode ser sobrecarregado), o segundo exemplo não faria sentido na linguagem. E, é claro, o operador `~` não existe.

Se você quiser sobrecarregar os operadores que podem e usar no lugar correto, então eu digo para não fazer.

Você tem certeza que sabe o que está fazendo? Conhece todas implicações? Vai fazer algo útil com ele? Será intuitivo para quem vai usar? Ou seja, o programador que vai usar seu operador vai entender o que está acontecendo ali?

Pouquíssimos tipos precisam ter seus próprios operadores e eles são os que possuem equivalência na matemática. De preferência em coisas óbvias. Não é para abusar da sobrecarga de operadores. Não é para criar para qualquer coisa, não é para fazer uso criativo. Tem linguagem que optou por não ter isto justamente para evitar abuso (o que eu discordo, porque qualquer coisa pode ser abusada).

Se vai mesmo fazer isto, um bom começo é ler todo o [tutorial "oficial"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) com muita atenção, ler a documentação, a especificação e pesquisar muito sobre o assunto.

Entenda que [os operadores são estáticos](https://web.archive.org/web/20151104042040/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/05/14/why-are-overloaded-operators-always-static-in-c.aspx). Entenda que alguns operadores podem sugerir um comportamento que exija um código específico para que tudo ocorra bem (apenas [um exemplo](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55984&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) disto).

Talvez o operador que faça mais sentido em alguns tipos é o *cast* implícito ou explícito. E este quase ninguém pensa. As pessoas não são tão criativas assim. Mesmo este pode ser abusado. Mas é mais comum você precisar de um operador para converter de um tipo para outro que fazer de conta que um símbolo de `+` faça algo diferente, afinal este símbolo só deve ser usado para adição, de preferência numérica. Já há polêmica se deveria ser usado para texto, como é usado na linguagem. Mesmo assim há quem prefira fazer um método conversor de tipo do que usar o operador em casos não tão claros.

Outro operador onde é comum fazer sobrecarga é o da igualdade, onde já foi dito que precisa ter certeza que entende como ele funciona.

Exemplo real de uso em um tipo que faz sentido (forma extremamente simplificada):

```
using static System.Console;

class Complex {
    private int real;
    private int imaginary;
    public Complex(int i, int j) {
        real = i;
        imaginary = j;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object o) => ((Complex)o).real == this.real && ((Complex)o).imaginary == this.imaginary;
    public override string ToString() => string.Format("{0} + {1}i", real, imaginary);
    public override int GetHashCode() => this.ToString().GetHashCode();
    public static bool operator == (Complex x, Complex y) => x.Equals(y);
    public static bool operator != (Complex x, Complex y) => !x.Equals(y);
    public static Complex operator +(Complex x, Complex y) => new Complex(x.real + y.real, x.imaginary + y.imaginary);
}
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var x = new Complex(10,20);
        WriteLine(x);
        var y = new Complex(10,20);
        WriteLine(y);
        var z = y;
        WriteLine(z);
        if (x == y) WriteLine("z igual y");
        else WriteLine("x diferente y");
        if (y != z) WriteLine("y diferente z"); 
        else WriteLine("y igual z");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/vTF2tt). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dxgsbw). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/Overload.cs).

Vou reforçar: quase todas as ideias que as pessoas têm para fazer sobrecarga de operador não devem ser feitas. Os melhores lugares onde ele cabia já foi feito na linguagem.

Answer (score 4):

Não sei se seria possivel criar um simbolo exclusivo para você, mas é possivel você dar um "override" em um determinado operador normal utilizando uma classe.

```
public class TesteOperador
{
    public float valor
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public TesteOperador (float valor)
    {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    //ou retornando um tipo especifico que você queira... int, float
    public static TesteOperador operator + (TesteOperador A, TesteOperador B)
    {
        return new TesteOperador((A.valor * 2) + (B.valor * 2) / (5));
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/jXrmHR