# Sobrecarga de operadores em C#

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem, operadores, sobrecarga

Possuo algumas dúvidas sobre sobrecarga de operadores em C#.

1. Para que serve?
2. O seu conceito  é o mesmo de *overload* em métodos Java?
3. Existe algum exemplo prático de fazer tal procedimento no dia a dia?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é sobrecarga de operadores?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61034/o-que-%c3%a9-sobrecarga-de-operadores)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Para que serve?

Para "criar" operadores em determinados tipos. Não que possa criar um operador novo, mas como o nome diz pode sobrecarregar um operador existente de forma apropriada para esse tipo em específico.

Quase sempre só faz sentido em tipos que expressam grandezas matemáticas simples e claras, comumente é um tipo por valor, mas em matriz também é comum.

Sem essa funcionalidade teríamos que usar métodos para fazer o mesmo. De fato o operador não deixa de ser um método, mas na hora de consumi-lo a sintaxe é muito mais agradável, se criado com bom senso e bom gosto.

Boa parte dos tipos, para não dizer todos, faz muito sentido ter o operador `==`, sem ele teria que usar o método `Equals()` ou `ReferenceEquals()`.

Não se deve fazer maluquices com esses operadores. Algumas pessoas criticam a linguagem permitir isso porque uma pessoa pode fazer o operador `+` subtrair alguma coisa. Mas porque você faria isso? Só um maluco faz. Mas tudo na linguagem pode ser abusado, então é algo bom.

Só não tente usar um símbolo para algo que não tem relação com o que ele indica ser, não é para usar a esmo só pra ficar mais curto digitar algo na hora do uso. Já há críticas se o `+` deveria ser usado para concatenar `string`. Eu não vejo problemas, mesmo sendo um pouco diferente do usual na matemática faz algum sentido.

As regras de precedência ou associatividade do operador não muda nada.

Tem que tomar alguns cuidados e conhecer bem todas as consequências antes de usar este mecanismo. Não é tão trivial a sua adoção. As regras de uso do C# são diferentes de outras linguagens, como o C++, por exemplo. Por exemplo eles só podem ser métodos estáticos, assim o compilador consegue mais facilmente trocar a ordem de uso.

Em classes normais é raro ter seu uso, exceto o operador de indexação, e eventualmente de *cast*. Mesmo em `structs`s a maioria dos casos não precisa, a não ser, talvez, *cast* (e quase ninguém cria).

> O seu conceito é o mesmo de overload em métodos Java?

Sim, e é igual ao *overload* do C# também. O operador não deixa de ser um método, apenas tem nome e regra especial.

Por Java não ter isso tem algumas expressões esquisitas e longas.

> Existe algum exemplo prático de fazer tal procedimento no dia a dia?

O exemplo mais óbvio que todos usam é o [`Complex`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Runtime.Numerics/System/Numerics/Complex.cs,3e2d1e25b7131757) (veja os fontes aí). Outro bem usado é o [`Decimal`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Decimal.cs,1b2858baf311cbf9). Já [`Matrix3D`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml/System/Windows/Media/Media3D/Matrix3D.cs,77365625a5f7bd09) é um um pouco mais complexo, mas que não foi implementado de forma muito adequada. Sem falar em `String` como já dito (embora seja providenciado pela linguagem). Notou que estes casos não há abuso e faz sentido ter operadores?

Veja mais em [Como criar operadores em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89577/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).